# Combining probability density funciton and probability mass function

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability, geometric-probability

I was working on this problem:

`Let N be a geometric random variable with parameter p. Suppose that the conditional distribution of X given that N = n is the gamma distribution with parameters n and λ. Find the conditional probability mass function of N given that X = x.`

And in the solution, they started with
$$P(N=n|X=x)=\frac{f_{X|N}(x|n)P(N=n)}{f_{X}(x)}$$

However why is that they can simply combine the p.d.f. of X conditioned on N with the p.m.f. of N? Pmf expresses probability while pdf is a probability density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bayes' Theorem does hold with $N$ being a discrete r.v. and $X$ being a continuous r.v. You can see page 6 of this [document](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.gatech.edu/dist/2/436/files/2017/08/16_BayesRVs-su14.pdf) for a proof.